# in heroku, is there any way I can get unlimited history of logging?

Tags: logging, heroku

It is really a pain to not have that. I have a java Spring app that can not start in heroku but I can not see all history logs which made it very difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve this would be to use a syslog drain in your application to a service like [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) or [Loggly](http://www.loggly.com/) which would then retain your logs for a wider time frame. These services provide almost near live logging and notifications based on the contents of your logs which is useful for errors and scaling.

Comment: Yeah, it probably wouldn't be to hard to pipe the logs to S3 or something.